# Passing data from table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

in my iOS app the user can select a hostname in a table view. This hostname should be transferred to a detail view controller.

**TableViewController**

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
     UITableView *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     NSLog(@"%@", self.cell.textLabel.text);
     DPPingViewController *objectOfPingViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
     objectOfPingViewController.string = (NSString *)sender;
 }
```

**DetailViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.ipAddr.text = _string;
    //self.ipAddr.text = @"192.168.178.1";
    self.results.text = @"";
    NSLog(@"Zelle: %@", _string);

}
```

NSLOG

```
2014-07-15 11:52:37.646 EasyTest[3623:90946] Zelle: <UITableViewCell: 0xc17fe30; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'Apple.com'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xc1800c0>>
```

Why doesn't the NSLog shows only "Apple.com". Where does the other informations come from?

Comment: Can you show the line from cellForRowAtIndexPath: method where you setup cell.textLabel.text = ...; ?

Comment: why you are doing this "objectOfPingViewController.string = (NSString *)sender;" , here you are sending the tableviewcell to next controller. it should be "cell.textLabel.text"

Comment: `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"hostCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = self.hostMutableArray[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `sender` for the segue is actually the `UITableViewCell`, and not the string content you want, which would make sense from how you configure it in the story board. Instead of casting the sender to an NSString, you probably want to do something like:

```
UITableViewCell *sourceCell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;
objectOfPingViewController.string = sourceCell.textLabel.text;
```

That should get you the actual string content, rather than an entire table cell, which is a view class with a bunch of other parameters along for the ride.

Comment: sourceCell.text should be @"sourceCell.textLabel.text"

Comment: `objectOfPingViewController.string = cell.textLabel.text;` Property 'textLabel' not found on object of type 'UITableView *' What does that mean?